# Data factory activity to read both ifelse true/false activity output

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Expectation is to read output of If else condition based on True or False and the immediate activity should read either of the activity output.

As we cant name same activity name for both True and False, I need to name it unique but to read either of one activity like an "Or" condition is there a possibility as at any time only 1 activity output be avaialble.[image]

True  - adfactvtyfilter_activities_1
False - adfactvtyfilter_activities_2

So on completion of If else proceeding activity should check for @activity('adfactvtyfilter_activities_1').output.value or @activity('adfactvtyfilter_activities_2').output.value, whichever is available.

Comment: Did you try storing the output into a variable using set variable activity in If Condition and use the variable in the next activities? You can use the same variable to store the output of True & False activities.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @NiharikaMoola-MT. Your suggestion worked perfectly

Comment: Glad it worked! posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a **pipeline variable** to store the output of an activity.
2. In the `If condition` activity, use `Set variable` activity to **store** the output value of the previous activity.
3. Use the same variable for True and False condition activities as only 1 condition executes at a time.
4. Use the variable output in the next steps as required.

**True activities:**

[image]

**False activities:**

[image]